# Merging objects and removing duplicates based on field value

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutablearray

I am working on a JSON `NSMutableArray`, the fields are stored in objects, which are then stored in an `NSMutableArray`. Now by the virtue of the way the database is designed, the topmost fields (what I call categories), repeat. I am trying to merge the duplicates, for example
an object called play has (playname, playdate, playCharacters). PlayCharacters is also an NSmutableArray, so a playName can have one or more playcharacters

All play objects are stored in a final `NSMutableArray` called; playList. 
My code eliminate the duplicates, but I do not just want to remove duplicates, I want to merge them

For example
[Tennis - (date: played on Thursdays), (playCharacters: moses, john, ken)

[Tennis - (date: played on fridays), (playCharacters: leo, bill)]

What I want is

[Tennis-(date: played on Thursdays, played on Fridays),(playCharacters: leo, bill, moses, john, Ken) ]

My code so far only eliminates the duplicates as shown

```
   NSMutableSet *present = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSUInteger y = 0;

    while (y < [playList count]) {
        id obj = [playList objectAtIndex:y];

        if ([present containsObject:obj]) {

            [playList removeObjectAtIndex:y];

        } else {
            [present addObject:obj];
            y++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can try dictionary where you can set key for desired objects.

Comment: No I dont want to use dictionary

Comment: use @distinctUnionOfObjects for removing duplicates.

Comment: @prasad_R, I have not tried that but my guess is that it is probably key- value just like NSDictionary. I am avoiding that because I intend to build this to a higher hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom object that will contain the information like (nssstring playname,nsdate playdate,nsmutablearray playCharacters).As per your requirement you add this objects to an nsarray. Then you create a function that will merge all the objects based on name. In this function it will loop through all the objects and then merge it an new array.

```
-(void)someFunction{
NSMutableArray *newArray=[NSMutableArray array];

for (MyObj *obj in playList) {
    NSMutableArray *present=[playList copy];//perform deep copy rather than shallow
    if ([playList containsObject:obj]) {
        //filter the array by gameName and get the new array containg similar names using nspredicates
        [present filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
            MyObj *customObject=(MyObj *) evaluatedObject;
            return (customObject.gameName!=obj.gameName);
        }]];
        //write code to merge the players * dates
            //LOOP throug the present and merge it to singe object
        //then remove objs from playList array
        [playList removeObjectsInArray:present];
    }
}
```

}

Try this code i havent tested but it might work

Comment: I like your answer jay, could you please give an example for the function part